# Is there a hook that runs when exiting read-only-mode?

Tags: hooks, read-only-mode

I'd like to set some things (e.g., cursor shape) when in `read-only-mode`. That part is easy enough with

```
  (add-hook 'read-only-mode-hook 
             (lambda() (setq-local cursor-type 'box)))
```

Then I'd like to switch it back when exiting `read-only-mode`. Something like

```
  (add-hook 'read-write-mode-hook 
             (lambda() (setq-local cursor-type 'bar)))
```

except that there is no such thing as `read-write-mode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like all minor mode hooks, `read-only-mode-hook` runs when entering *or leaving* read-only mode. So you only need to make the setting of the cursor a bit smarter, probably by checking the value of `buffer-read-only` and acting appropriately.

Comment: Ah, I have achieved enlightenment, and all it cost me was the embarrassment of asking a stupid question in the internet.

Comment: @Stefan.  Interesting.  I understand this is because of the "toggle" nature of minor modes but I can't find any explicit mention of it in the documentation.  Did I miss it?

Comment: The doc for `read-only-mode-hook` explicitly mentions "entering or leaving". Not sure about a more general statement, although the `define-minor-mode` doc in the Elisp manual say that it runs `MODE-hook`, but you still have to make the connection that it runs it whenever it is called (i.e. both entering and leaving) which I had not made before @Stefan pointed it out.

Comment: At present you could still use `MODE-on-hook` and `MODE-off-hook` for minor modes, but the code indicates that these are only there for backwards-compatibility, so they might be removed at some point in the future. The intention is certainly that you use `MODE-hook` and test the value of the `MODE` variable.

Comment: @ista: thanks for your "stupid question" - I think it enlightened quite a few of us!

Comment: One thing isn't clear though, even from the docs I can find: does it run before, or after, `buffer-read-only` gets set?  My experiments say after, so if `buffer-read-only` is `t` inside the hook, we're *entering* `read-only-mode`.